# my unity program stucks when getting files from http server

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine, httpserver, get-request

There are two buttons in my program,
I get the file with bin extension from the address given with the get button. The operation was successful. When I press the test button, it says "test" on the console.
That is all.
However, when I press the get button, I cannot press the test button until the get request is completed. This is my problem.
What I want is that the get request continues in the background and I can click on other buttons.
What would you recommend me to do?

Get Button function :

public void get()
{

```
   StartCoroutine(Get());
}

private IEnumerator Get()
{

        
        string Url = "http://my/local/server/file.bin";
        Debug.Log(Url);

        using (UnityWebRequest unityWebRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(Url))
        {
           
            yield return unityWebRequest.SendWebRequest();

            if (unityWebRequest.isNetworkError || unityWebRequest.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log("error");
            }
            else
            {
                 byte[] results = unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.data;
             
                Debug.Log("Received: " + unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.text);
                 Debug.Log("Size: " + results.Length ); }      
         }
}
```

and simple test button :

```
public void print()
    {
        Debug.Log("test");
    }
```

[image]As I said, both work separately. What I want is that the Test button is not blocked while doing the getting file from HTTP server.

(btw file size is 100mb)

Answer (score 0):

Just glancing through the documentation, it looks like the lockup may be happening when you call:

```
byte[] results = unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.data;
```

The getter on data for the default downloadHandler appears to run a protected method to actually download the content. That download runs on the main thread by default, and is likely what's locking up your UI.

You could confirm this by adding log statements:

```
Debug.Log("Before get data");
byte[] results = unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.data;
Debug.Log("After get data");
```

and checking if there's a substantial delay between the two log statements in which the UI is frozen.

If that's the case, it looks like you should be able to attach a custom downloadHandler to run on a background thread and not block the UI thread.

[DownloadHandler.GetData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandler.GetData.html)

[DownloadHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.DownloadHandler.html)

To avoid using a custom downloadHandler, you could insert the following

```
while (!unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.isDone)
    yield return null;

byte[] results = unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.data;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I see these two outputs after the delay. I mean; the get request is completed, the program is locked in the meantime and then I see the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be the Debug.Log you are trying to do. You can delete this line below and try it.

```
Debug.Log ("Received:" + unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.text);
```